# Which integration of tan x is correct?

Tags: integration, derivatives, indefinite-integrals

Integration of `tan x` as given by [http://www.wolframalpha.com](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sinx%2Fcosx) is this: 
[image]

And my teacher suggested this one:
[image]

Are these both right answers?

Comment: the log there is the natural log

Comment: Have you tried to differentiate both $-\log(\cos(x))$ and $\ln|\sec(x)|$ ? If you get the same answer after a few simplifications, then the integrals are both right. The answer given by Wolfram should contain an absolute value.

Comment: Absolutely. Your teacher is a fierce foe of minus signs, while Wolfram Alpha is not, that's the main difference.

Comment: You must admit that $\sec$ isn't a function you meet every day, even if it has a kind of old-fashioned charm. As far as I'm concerned, insisting on it borders on hipsterdom.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $\cos x = \frac{1}{\sec x}$, and $\ln \frac{1}{x} = -\ln x$, for $x > 0$

Answer (score 0):

Let $$\displaystyle I = \int \tan xdx = \int\frac{\sin x}{\cos x}dx\;,$$ Now Put $\cos x = t\;,$ then $\sin xdx = -dt$

So $$\displaystyle I = -\int\frac{1}{t}dt = -\ln |t|+\mathcal{C} = -\ln|\cos x|+\mathcal{C} = \ln\left|\frac{1}{\cos x}\right|+\mathcal{C} = \ln|\sec x|+\mathcal{C}$$

Above we have use $$\displaystyle \bullet \; n\ln(m) = \ln(m)^{n}$$

Answer (score 0):

The second one $\;\ln |\sec x|+C$ is **wrong** for complex variable $x$.  If you do not tell Alpha differently, it assumes you want a complex variable.  The two answers agree (perhaps up to a constant term) on any interval in the real line where $\tan(x)$ is defined.  In that sense, they are both **right**.